# What is the recomended TFS build template for FAKE integration?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, f#-fake

FAKE documentation has description for integrating with TeamCity but there is no detailed description on TFS integration.

I think I need a custom build process template but before I create one I wanted to make sure that none exists.

Could you recommend me TFS template that integrates FAKE?

Comment: http://ctaggart.github.io/SourceLink/tfs.html looks like it may do the job. I'm trying to figure out if it requires adding the show source code feature that I think is the main purpose of SourceLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom activity that hosts and runs your FAKE process.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringFAKEAnFBuildSystemForAllOfNET.aspx

There is some good documentation online for creating custom activities:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2009/11/18/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx

And I recommend that you add it to the Community Build Tool project.

Comment: First result google/bing'ing that exact text: https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/